# PHPMyAdmin - Missing value in the form

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm currently trying to learn MySQL and have a problem that I was unable to solve.

I started to use the query window to give certain commands like:

```
CREATE DATABASE ijdb;
```

The problem is that whenever I do a command in the Query Window, I get the following:

[image]

Any hints on how to debug this? Tried numerous wamp servers on windows and all of them give me the same pop-up when trying to use PHPMyAdmin Query Window.

If It helps:
I'm currently using : BitNami Wamp Stack 5.4.24-0 and latest version of Google Chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try other client,like Heidisql.

Comment: A quick google seems to suggest it's a compatibility problem between phpmyadmin and some versions of browsers. Try a different browser.

Comment: @Phil I keep getting that error in IE but seems like queries get executed using IE so thank you so much. Now I can finally continue my learning.

Answer (score 1):

- Close this Query window.
- Click home button in the top left corner below the phpMyAdmin logo.

  [image]
- Click on the database ijdb, to RUN QUERIES on DATABASE ijdb
- CLick the tab SQL which is second from left in the menu.
- Enter the query and run it. It should work now.

[Read this reference book - PHP & MySQL: Novice to Ninja](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjC6sO5tvfIAhXCo5QKHSVfDKM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitepoint.com%2Fstore%2Fphp-mysql-novice-to-ninja%2F&usg=AFQjCNGYAWEazj6FYXdNhua8lkGfHOkRrg&sig2=3S5zP4sT3DfKIsQfd04I0A)